# associative array pointers / traversing associative array

Tags: php, arrays, traversal

Does `next()` and `prev()` work on associative arrays?

I'm trying to traverse through a dataset that uses two records to describe one "game" if you will. So when I'm on the second record w/ matching id i need to look at the record before and grab `eg_item['final_score']`.

```
{"id":"75", "team_name":"TEAM1", "home_team_name":"TEAM1", "image":"TEAM1_HOME.png", "final_score":"37"}, 
{"id":"75", "team_name":"TEAM2", "home_team_name":"TEAM2", "image":"TEAM2_AWAY.png", "final_score":"10"}, 
{"id":"76", "team_name":"TEAM1", "home_team_name":"TEAM1", "image":"TEAM1_HOME.png", "final_score":"10"}, 
{"id":"76", "team_name":"TEAM2", "home_team_name":"TEAM2", "image":"TEAM2_AWAY.png", "final_score":"14"},
```

All of the examples I'm finding use lame `array('one','two',three')` type examples that just don't help.

code sample:

```
foreach( $json_output as $eg_item ) :

    if( $this_game_id == $last_game_id ) :
        // get this records info
        $b_score = $eg_item['final_score'];
        $b_team_name = $eg_item['team_name'];
        prev( $json_output );
            // get previous records info
        $a_score = $eg_item['final_score'];
        $a_team_name = $eg_item['team_name'];
        $a_game_id = $eg_item['id'];
        // put pointer back
        next( $json_output );    
    else :  
        // skip next record     
    endif;

endforeach;
```

Comment: Yes they work on assoc arrays. Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like an array of associative arrays, right? If so, loop through them by index 2 at a time, then you can look at the current inner array and the previous inner array in each iteration of the loop:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i+= 2) {
  $current = $array[$i];
  $last = $array[$i-1];
  //$current['final_score'], $last['final_score'], etc
}
```

Comment: that'll do dan.  from what i'm reading, given my large feed size i'm better off using for anyhow.  much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes they work just fine, heres a small test case i have done:

```
<?php
$sample = array(
    "first" => Array("a","d","c"),
    "second" => Array("a","d","c"),
    "third" => Array("a","d","c"),
    "fourth" => Array("a","d","c")
);

while(next($sample))
{
    $item = current($sample);
    echo key($sample) . "\n";

    if(is_array($item))
    {
        echo "\t" . current($item) . "\n";
        while(next($item))
        {
            echo "\t" . current($item) . "\n";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

output: http://codepad.org/2ZeqzWcx